# Visual Studio Don't have permission to run program I just built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10

I'm building a C# program that was working a few minutes ago. And when I try to run it, either in the debugger or from explorer. I get the error "Access Denied." running it directly. Visual Studio 2019 says "Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program 'path\to\file.exe'. Access Denied." Run as administrator doesn't help.

Then, this is the weird part, the executable disappears.

I have full permission to the directory. Building the project produces no errors.

Web searching gave "How to clear visual studio cache". Doing that did not help.

EDIT: Let me reiterate. The compiler creates the executable. It is there. I   can copy the executable to other directories. But running the file says I don't have permission to run the file. The file is not signed in any manner. And the program was working minutes before this started happening. Other projects build and run without issue.

EDIT2: I copied the project to a new name/directory and it works without issue. I'm going to assume it is the antivirus software.

Comment: almost certainly you have another instance of the program running already

Comment: @pm100, No, I rebooted. There's no other instance running. Also, I've tried renaming the file. And it still doesn't run.

Comment: Can you check your AV software? I had this last year and my freshly compiled exe file was deleted pretty much right after being built until I told my AV that all my VS folders were safe.

Comment: If only I had permission to change my AV software.

Comment: ok, this is what I would do, install sysinternals procmon and watch what file operation is failing. It will show you every single IO done by every app together with the result

Comment: The app isn't starting.

Comment: yes but VS is having a problem or the c compiler, you can see what those things are barfing on

Comment: The compiler creates the executable with no errors. There's a file. It's running the file that causes the display of Access Denied and then get deleted by something.

Comment: Sounds exactly like something an antivirus would do!

Comment: _If only I had permission to change my AV software_ Well, sombody should be able to change the settings; if you can't, do ask your admin. Folders in a develpoer machine really need to be excluded from the scans..

Comment: Yes, it's just getting them to understand the issue that is always a pain.